# Проброс запроса из docker контейнера

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cluster, containers

Есть kubernetes job который ходит в базу и за тем отправляет http запрос. База реальная и находится в совершенно другом месте, данные с нее я удачно получаю. А в качестве хттп сервера я использую заглушку которую развернул на своем компьютере. В качестве кластера использую minikube. Вопрос в том как отправить хттп запрос из докера, который находится в minikube, на localhost машины на которой запущен minikube

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать **host.docker.internal** вместо **localhost**.

Дополнительное чтение по теме: [How to connect to the Docker host from inside a Docker container?](https://medium.com/@TimvanBaarsen/how-to-connect-to-the-docker-host-from-inside-a-docker-container-112b4c71bc66)

Comment: host.docker.internal работает не на всех ОС и/или версиях docker и требует дополнительной конфигурации.

Comment: Да, спасибо за замечание. В приложенной ссылке есть информация об ограничениях, но по описанию задачи могло сработать без дополнительных настроек.